# Are there cheaper alternatives to cloud watch logs for creating dash boards?

Tags: metrics, grafana

Iv set up a grafana instance.

I want to create dashboards to get metrics on lambda functions but useing cloud watch logs would be expencive.

Are there any cheaper alternatives to achive this that might be worth looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grafana was not really built to view logs from the get go.

They however introduced this feature in v6.0 via the [Explore tab](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/explore/)

This can be leveraged in 2 ways.

### Via Elasticsearch data source (in v6.3+)

Check the [Elasticsearch docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/elasticsearch/#logs-beta%20for%20more) for more.

If you want, you can still integrate this with Cloudwatch. Check out the [log subscirber-consumer solution](https://github.com/amazon-archives/cloudwatch-logs-subscription-consumer) & [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html)

### Via Loki & AWS Lambda

If you want to stick to Cloudwatch as your primary source of logs, you can create a Lambda function that ships them to Loki which in tern can be used in Grafana as a data source. See [1](https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/integrating-cloudwatch-logs-with-grafanas-loki/), [2](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/loki/) & [3](https://roobert.github.io/2020/01/12/Cloudwatch-Loki-Shipper/)